# "Nice Angles" - Code Eval challenge

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, formatting, exception, unit-conversion

Out of fun, I solved ["Nice Angles" challenge on CodeEval](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/160/) in C# 4.0:

> **CHALLENGE DESCRIPTION:**
>
> Write a program that outputs the value of angle, reducing its
>   fractional part to minutes and seconds.
>
> **INPUT SAMPLE:**
>
> The first argument is a path to a file that contains the values of
>   angles with their decimal fractions:
>
> ```
> 330.39991833
> 0.001
> 14.64530319
> 0.25
> 254.16991217
> ```
>
> **OUTPUT SAMPLE:**
>
> Print to stdout values of angles with their fractional parts reduced
>   to minutes and seconds.
>
> The whole and fractional parts are separated by period, minutes are
>   separated by apostrophe, seconds by double quotes. The values of
>   minutes and seconds are shown as two numbers (with leading zeros if
>   needed).
>
> ```
>  330.23'59"
>  0.00'03"
>  14.38'43"
>  0.15'00"
>  254.10'11"
> ```

This is the code I used to solve the problem:

```
public static void ConvertToMinSec(string path)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path))
            {


                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var degreeValues = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(degreeValues))
                    {
                        var totalVal = degreeValues.Split('.');
                        if (totalVal.Length == 1)
                        {
                            var temp = totalVal[0] + ".0";
                            totalVal = temp.Split('.');
                        }
                        var intPart = totalVal[0];
                        var decimalPart =  "0." + totalVal[1];
                        decimal minutes;
                        decimal.TryParse(decimalPart, out minutes);

                        minutes = decimal.Multiply(minutes, 60);
                        var minutePart = (int)minutes;
                        var remainingDecimal = minutes.ToString().Split('.');
                        if (remainingDecimal.Length == 1)
                        {
                            var tempDecimal = remainingDecimal[0] + ".0";
                            remainingDecimal = tempDecimal.Split('.');
                        }


                        decimal seconds;
                        decimal.TryParse("0." + remainingDecimal[1], out seconds);
                        seconds = seconds*60;
                        var secondsPart = (int) seconds;
                        var report = string.Format("{0}"+"."+"{1:00}"+"'"+"{2:00}"+'"', intPart,
                            minutePart, secondsPart);

                        Console.WriteLine(report);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What about "180" without the decimal point?

Comment: I think that problem is not in decimal separators - they are clearly described in the task as dots, so I assume no problem here. However do check this line of yours:

    `var report = string.Format("{0}" + "." + "{1:00}" + "'" + "{2:00}" + "''", intPart, minutePart, secondsPart);`

You used two apsothropes for seconds separator (`"''"`) while they just used doublequete in description. Try changing this string into that - `"\""`.

Comment: @SebGruch thank you for your response. As I mentioned in the question, the error is due to IndexOutOfRange exception, which is happening for an input of 180.0 or 90.0 or such numbers on the CodeEval server. I contacted them, and they say that there might be a difference in their C# 4 compiler than my C# 4 compiler on my machine, which I am not convinced. I am working on another solution to this problem, which I will post it when it is completed.

Comment: [On-topic Help Center Hints](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): ***To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?*** This looks like question from gray zone, where it seems that the code works for most cases, but may fail in other. I am not sure where this belongs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the heart of the solution, there should be a function that converts decimal degrees into a d°mm'ss" string.  Assuming that the input is in a reasonable domain (between 0 and 360, for example), the conversion algorithm should be simple and regular.  Above all, it should be purely mathematical at this point — you shouldn't be trying to do any string parsing.

Your format string had lots of unnecessary concatenation.

```
public static string ToDegMinSec(double dec)
{
    int degrees = (int)dec;
    dec = 60 * (dec - degrees);
    int minutes = (int)dec;
    dec = 60 * (dec - minutes);
    int seconds = (int)dec;
    return string.Format("{0}.{1:00}'{2:00}\"", degrees, minutes, seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var minutes = Convert.ToDecimal("0." + totalVal[1])*60;
var remainingDecimal = minutes.ToString().Split('.');
```

I think the issue is that `Decimal.ToString`'s formatting will depend on the current culture. A computer with different settings will produce different results. The settings on your computer is such that it produces `0.0` here. But it could produce `0,0`, `0`, or various other crazy things.

As a general practice, don't use the result of `.ToString()` in computations. It's almost always the wrong way.

Comment: `ToString(`[`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`)`, same with parsing.